# Merging dataframes but select columns to keep based on file

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have two dataframes, An original one with comments in some columns and some values and an updated one that has updated values but not the original comments. I would like to know if there's a way to select the columns I want to keep based on the file from which the info is coming

df1:

```
ID DATA1 DATA2 DATA3    DATA4   DATA5 DATA9
  1   10   10     ''      ''       X   99
  2   10   10    'error'  ''           99
  3   10   10     ''      'error'      99
```

df2:

```
ID DATA1 DATA2 DATA3    DATA4   DATA5 DATA6 DATA7
  1   13   10     ''      ''       X    
  2   15   25     ''      ''            X
  3   10   10     ''      ''               'error'
```

desired result:

```
ID DATA1 DATA2  DATA3    DATA4     DATA5 DATA6  DATA7  DATA9
  1   13   10      ''      ''        X                   99
  2   15   25    'error'   ''              X             99
  3   10   10      ''    'error'               'error'   99
```

Right now I've tried finding a simple solution (I know this can be done manually) since there are a lot of columns in both files and manually setting which columns I'll keep might not be the best option

**EDIT**  I forgot to mention that the dataframes might not always have the same number of columns and I need to retain all the information and update anything that comes updated in a new file. Thank in advance.

Comment: Would the two dataframes have same common columns? I think you can use merge function with left outer join. This will keep common columns from original dataframe along with all the updated columns from updated dataframe.

Comment: @smandape no, they will share some columns, but not all of them, and i have to keep the values of the original one for some columns but update everything else with the second data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can  just assign the columns ('DATA3', 'DATA4') values from first dataset to the second one

```
df2[4:5] <- df1[4:5]
```

Comment: Sorry, I needed to say that I need to do a join, since not always the files will have the same columns. I'll edit the qustion.

Comment: @AaronParrilla  please edit your quesiton.  THe example looks so simple

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems that you have some idea about which columns should be kept in the updated data.frame (correct me if I am wrong). In this case, with base R you could do e.g.,

```r
keepCols <- c("DATA3", "DATA4")

(df <- cbind(df2[, !(names(df2) %in% keepCols)], df1[, keepCols]))
#>   ID DATA1 DATA2 DATA5 DATA6 DATA7 DATA9 DATA3 DATA4
#> 1  1    13    10     X                99            
#> 2  2    15    25           X          99 error      
#> 3  3    10    10             error    99       error

## reorder columns if necessary
df[, c("ID", sort(setdiff(names(df), "ID")))]
#>   ID DATA1 DATA2 DATA3 DATA4 DATA5 DATA6 DATA7 DATA9
#> 1  1    13    10                 X                99
#> 2  2    15    25 error                 X          99
#> 3  3    10    10       error             error    99
```